# Информация об изменении в другом Activity

Tags: android

Есть первое Activity, в нём textView с информацией, она записывается из бд. Открываю другое активити для редактирования. После редактирования закрываю второе активити. Необходимо дать знать первому Activity, что произошли изменения информации. Вариант делать обновление в Start() не подходит, поскольку из этого активити открываются так же и другие.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать `startActivityForResult()` вместо `startActivity()`
И в нужный момент отдавать результат например:

`setResult(RESULT_OK, intent)`

или

```
setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, intent)
```

результат обрабатывать необходимо в:

```
onActivityResult
```

В целом ваш вопрос можно решить большим кол-ом путей, но для этого надо более подробно знать что происходит. А пока можете ознакомиться: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result?hl=ru

Answer (score 0):

Данная задача очень грамотно решается при помощи использования  [Architecture Component](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/). При этом для передачи информации можно воспользоваться классами приложения описывающими ViewModel.