# Как передать данные в onActivityResult при создании Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT

Tags: android, kotlin

Как передать данные в onActivityResult при создании Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT. То есть,  создаю новый интент:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT)
intent.type = "*/*"
intent.putExtra("data", "mesage")
startActivityForResult(intent, 500)
```

Запускается окно, где можно создать file. После того как файл создан, запускается onActivityResult.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    when (requestCode) {
        500 -> {
            val message = data?.getStringExtra("data")
        }
    }
}
```

В итоге message  == null.
Как мне передать сообщение?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Информация об изменении в другом Activity](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/855948/%d0%98%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bc-activity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну как минимум вам нужно в вызываемой активити положить какой-то результат:

```
val data = Intent().putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message)
setResult(RESULT_OK, data)
```

В [документации](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) можно поглядеть более подробно, а вот [тут](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/69-urok-30-podrobnee-pro-onactivityresult-zachem-nuzhny-requestcode-i-resultcode.html) есть норм урок по этой теме.

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, по подробнее, данный код написать до startActivityForResult(intent, 500)

Comment: Его не в startActivity писать надо. А в активити которую вы открываете из startActivityForResult. Тогда когда вызываемая активити закроется вы сможете в первой активити в onActivityResult получить результат

Comment: Нет конечно. Что такое startActivityForResult? Это метод который запускает активити и ждет от нее результат. Условно из активити А вы запустили активити Б, в активити Б что-то сделали и хотите получить в активити А результат. Вот в активити А вы просто укаываете ключ, и в onActivityReslut обрабатываете ответ, а в активити Б вы указываете сам ответ как я показал в ответе